# Bike won't start even after tune up

Tags: motorcycle, troubleshooting, triumph

I have a 2004 Triumph Daytona 600 and I'm having lots of touble starting it and finding out what's wrong with it. I put in new park plugs, new battery, coils and fuel pump but it will not crank. All the components turn on like the fuel pump, starter, and dash but motor won't start. Could I have flooded it with too much fuel? Or do I need a new fuel pump?

I have a diagnostic tool coming in the mail to check and see what is really worng with it until then I though I could find some help here to at least get it started. Would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You say, "will not crank" ... do you mean it won't fire (pretend to start, kick over, act like it wants to run), or do you mean it won't even go around (rotating engine)? I'm assuming the first suggestion? In mechanic terms, we usually consider "not cranking" to mean the engine internals don't rotate.

Comment: Hey Paulster thanks for the reply. Sorry for the mix up. It's the first description, not cranking, pretends to start, kick over, and act like it wants to run but it doesn't. I've done it over and over and still no success. Is there something I can do to get it started other than pushing the start butter? Thanks.

Comment: You might try seeing if it will start using starting fluid (or possibly even brake/carb cleaner) by spraying it directly into the intake while cranking it over. If it will start, or pretend to start (cough/spit/chug more than otherwise), you more than likely have a fueling issue. If this doesn't help, it'd be a different direction.